# minipage alignment

Tags: minipage

the minipage i am creating should start at the end of the hyphen but it goes down by one line--why?--how to get the alignment with the hyphen?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}        % or load ’ graphicx ’ and ’ b l ind tex t ’ manually
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext\\
\raggedright {\underline {Shri Peter J, PScO/ SA Wing   }} --\hspace{1pt} \begin{minipage} [t][2cm][t]{1\textwidth}
    Please intimate the progress of the Board wef 13 May 2019 onwards for the info of Controller. On file.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `0.5\textwidth` as a width for your `minipage` because by using `1\textwidth` it is forced bellow the rest of the line

Comment: 0.5 works--thanks

Comment: Underfull \hbox (badness 1478) in paragraph at lines 156--157
--why do i get the above error? after changing to 0.5--any other alternative to minipage?

Comment: Check my answer... (I used the whole width in my answer) ... But this is not an error ... it is a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}        % or load ’ graphicx ’ and ’ b l ind tex t ’ manually
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\restofline}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext\\
\savebox\mybox{\hbox{\underline {Shri Peter J, PScO/ SA Wing } --\hskip 1pt}}
\noindent\usebox{\mybox}
\setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}
\begin{minipage} [t]{\restofline}
    Please intimate the progress of the Board wef 13 May 2019 onwards for the info of Controller. On file.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**Explaining:**

I saved in an `\hbox` named `\mybox` the width of the initial text in order to calculate it's width and use it later to find the `\restofline` width.

Then the minipage, used all the next width (but had to reduce it slightly because of minipage's `outer sep`)

Comment: \setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}---------which book can I get such expressions from?

Comment: @jsbibra ... I haven't read any book about LaTeX yet but I suggest to read the TeXbook and then source2e documentation. (I will do too). My knowledge is gained mostly here by trying to help people oslve some LaTeX problems.